# Magento : How to Display Products as Default Display Product

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, product, product-list

I want to display product same as magento displays in default when product is added. I added tab and when clicks on that tab it displays products but not with systematic design. I want to display product like this:

[image]

I added a tab in customer.xml

```
<customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink">
                <name>offer_product</name>
                <path>user/index/index</path>
                <label>My Offer Product</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
<!--         <update handle="customer_account"/> -->
    </customer_account>
```

This is my phtml file through which I displayed my products when clicked on my customised tab:

```
<?php
  $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*') ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')->setPageSize(10);
  foreach($products as $product):
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    $attribute_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('customerproduct')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
     if($attribute_value == 'Yes')
      {
       ?>
        <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200,200); ?>">
       <?php
       ?>
        <br />
       <?php
       echo $product->getName().'<br />';
       echo $product->getPrice();
      }
  endforeach;
?>
```

and this is my controller code :

```
<?php
class Test_User_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
 public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('user/account_dashboard')
        );
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Account'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

I got idea that, I have to include list.phtml to display my products as magento displays in default after adding products. But I don'y know how to do it.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your local.xml or xml file of your module

```
<user_index_index translate="label">
       <label>Custom Page</label>
          <reference name="head">
                 <action method="setTitle"><title>Custom Page</title></action> <!--Page Title-->
         </reference>
     <!-- Mage_Customer -->
     <update handle="customer_account"/>
      <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="user/custom" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
          <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
              <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
          </block>
          <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
          <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
          <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
          <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
          <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
          <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
          <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
      </block>
    </reference>
</user_index_index>
```

Create block class for collection

```
<?php
class Excellence_User_Block_Custom extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List{
    protected function _getProductCollection() {
        $this->_productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*') ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')->setPageSize(10);
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

your updated controller

```
<?php
class Excellence_User_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
 public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where should I call _getProductCollection() method that you defined on block file @Gopal Patel

Comment: it will call by default in product list template. just assign your product collection @Birju

Comment: its not working@Gopal Patel

Comment: any error?  your route tag is `user` or anything else?

Comment: Its showing the output same without design

Comment: have you update controller?  provide your updated codes @Birju

Comment: yes I have updated it. My content is present in user.phtml. I want to show the contents of user.phtml as the above image I mentioned@Gopal PAtel

Comment: Looks like you have not followed my steps @Birju add handel in your layout file and just render it from controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56220/discussion-between-birju-and-gopal-patel).